# How to see the mobile version of a Weebly page on Desktop Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, mobile-url

I'm trying to debug the mobile version of a [Weebly](http://weebly.com)-built website in Desktop Chrome. I have set up mobile emulation as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation#useragent-spoofing) and I'm entering the iOS 7 user-agent.

I can see the mobile version on pages such as [google.com](http://www.google.com) and [wikipedia.org](http://www.wikipedia.org), but Weebly keeps serving me the desktop website to the Chrome mobile emulator. Seeing the same website on iOS' Safari shows the mobile version.

How can I see the mobile version of Weebly websites on the desktop?

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on page-Click on Inspect Element-Click On Emulation

In Device Select "Apple Iphone 5".
In Screen Turn The Resolution To Full.
Make sure that screen,User Agent,And Sensor is Checked.

Comment: I keep getting the desktop version of the page, not the mobile one.

Comment: @rsanchezsaez Refresh the page after switching to iPhone 5

Comment: I refreshed, no difference.

Comment: Try adjusting zoom level of browser